# I want to add multi-language in osmdroid

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am using OSMdroid for offline map, but map displays in default English language because tiles downloaded are in English. Anyone have a solution on how to add different languages in tile or openstreetmap?

Here's my code ...

```
   context = MainActivity.this;
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    map.setMultiTouchControls(true);
    mapController = map.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(12);
    map.setMaxZoomLevel(17);
    map.useDataConnection();
    map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTOSM);
```

Now I want to load TileSource according to user required language like to some place information in English, Dutch, French etc. Or any other solution for multi-language.

Answer (score 1):

With raster [tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles), you will need a tile server for every language you want to support. This is quite heavy. The better solution would be switching to [vector tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Vector_tiles) e.g. by using [mapsforge](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mapsforge). With vector tiles you can simply render the names you want.

Comment: I use osmbonuspack for offline map and it has tile method how to implement vector tiles

Comment: change   map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTOSM);?

Comment: osmdroid doesn't support vector tiles as far as I know.

Comment: There's an adapter for maps forge

Comment: Which type of adapter?

Comment: According to [this issue](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/20) there has been a wrapper but it has been removed due to incompatibilities with newer mapsforge API. Google still finds some pages when searching for mapsforge and osmdroid. So if there is any solution please post it here.